# llvm getelementptr getting wrong value

Tags: c++, llvm

I'm learning llvm getelementptr instruction, and trying to get element from a struct. My struct is like this,

```cpp
struct Foo {
    int32_t a;
    int32_t b;
    int32_t c;
};
```

the corresponding llvm type:

```cpp
Type *getType() {
    vector<Type *> tps;
    tps.push_back(Type::getInt32Ty(TheContext));
    tps.push_back(Type::getInt32Ty(TheContext));
    tps.push_back(Type::getInt32Ty(TheContext));
    StructType *tp = StructType::create(TheContext, tps, "foo_type");
    return tp;
}
```

and a test function,

```
%foo_type = type { i32, i32, i32 }

define i32 @_func_(%foo_type) {
entry:
  %1 = alloca %foo_type
  store %foo_type %0, %foo_type* %1
  %2 = getelementptr %foo_type, %foo_type* %1, i32 0, i32 1
  %3 = load i32, i32* %2
  ret i32 %3
}
```

But by running the compiled function, I'm always getting the third element which is Foo::c, but not Foo::b, so what's wrong with my code? I think the problem might be the store instruction.

[Complete working program here](https://github.com/wenxingxing/kaleidoscope/blob/master/main.cpp)

**EDIT 2019.12.13**

by passing pointer as parameter, I get the right answer

```
define i32 @_func_(%foo_type*) {
entry:
  %1 = alloca %foo_type*
  store %foo_type* %0, %foo_type** %1
  %ptr = load %foo_type*, %foo_type** %1
  %2 = getelementptr %foo_type, %foo_type* %ptr, i32 0, i32 1
  %3 = load i32, i32* %2
  ret i32 %3
}
```

So the problem must be `FP(f)` is not actually passing `f` to the compiled function in the previous version.

Comment: If that solved your issue. Please add it as an answer :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you write the function in c and let clang emit IR for it, you could see this:

```cpp
struct Foo {
    int a;
    int b;
    int c;
};

int bar(Foo f) {
    return f.b;
}
```

```
define dso_local i32 @_Z3bar3Foo(i64, i32) #0 {
  %3 = alloca %struct.Foo, align 4
  %4 = alloca { i64, i32 }, align 4
  %5 = getelementptr inbounds { i64, i32 }, { i64, i32 }* %4, i32 0, i32 0
  store i64 %0, i64* %5, align 4
  %6 = getelementptr inbounds { i64, i32 }, { i64, i32 }* %4, i32 0, i32 1
  store i32 %1, i32* %6, align 4
  %7 = bitcast %struct.Foo* %3 to i8*
  %8 = bitcast { i64, i32 }* %4 to i8*
  call void @llvm.memcpy.p0i8.p0i8.i64(i8* align 4 %7, i8* align 4 %8, i64 12, i1 false)
  %9 = getelementptr inbounds %struct.Foo, %struct.Foo* %3, i32 0, i32 1
  %10 = load i32, i32* %9, align 4
  ret i32 %10
}
```

That means `bar(Foo())` is actually accepting `int64` and `int32` as parameters, not `Foo` itself. It may be some c/cpp ABI which I don't know much.

But when passing by pointer, there's no such problem, so it works as expected.